# Assigning an event to a <td> cell via a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand why I can add certain items to a  cell, such as 'id', and not other items such as an onclick.  My goal is to have a button pressed, which adds a row to a table (which works) - and set some values on the  that is generated/appended to the table.  I've noticed that I can step into the console and do:

rows[row_#].cells[cell_#].id = 'foo';

and have it appear in the table on the  and function; but the following will not appear on the :

rows[row_#].cells[cell_#].onclick = 'callEvent(this)';

Should I be assigning this differently?

```
<button type="button" id="btn_add_row" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<table class="table table-hover" id="sample_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th id='calculate'>Column B</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            //sample of the td I'd like the function to generate
            <td id='calculate' onclick='callEvent(this)'>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
// Code to add a row to the table and assign properties to new row
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("sample_table");
    var lastRow = table.length;
    var numberOfCols = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(lastRow);
    for (var i=0;i<numberOfCols;i++) {
        row.insertCell(i);
        if (table.rows[0].cells[i].id === 'calculate') {
// The calculate id will appear on the TD after running
            table.rows[i].id = 'calculate';
// The onclick event will not appear on the TD afer running
            table.rows[i].onclick='callEvent(this)';
        }

function callEvent(element) {
                console.log('Calculate event fired!');
}
</script>
```

Comment: is the `onclick` you're trying to add above a string? this has to be a function. try `onclick = callEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you are not supplying a callback function reference to your `onclick` property. You are supplying a string:

```
.onclick='callEvent(this)'
```

So, no function actually gets invoked when the `click` event occurs.

Next, you shouldn't be using event properties (like `onclick`) in your JavaScript or adding inline HTML event handling attributes at all (that technique is about 20 years old) as they:

1. Create "spaghetti code" that is difficult to read and debug.
2. Lead to duplication of code.
3. Don't scale well
4. Don't follow the **[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)** development methodology.
5. Create anonymous global wrapper functions around your attribute values that alter the `this` binding in your callback functions.
6. Don't follow the **[W3C Event Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)**.

Instead, do all your work in JavaScript and use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to set up event handlers.

Also (FYI) `id` attributes need to be unique, so when you create a new row or cell, don't reuse an already assigned `id`.

Here's an example:

```js
// Place all of this inside of a <script> element that is just before the 
// closing of the body (</body>)

// Get references to all elements that you'll be working with
var btnAddRow = document.getElementById("btn_add_row");
var tbl = document.getElementById("sample_table");

// Now, set up the event handling functions
btnAddRow.addEventListener("click", addRow);

// Code to add a row to the table and assign properties to new row
function addRow() {
    var counter = 1; // id attributes must be unique. This will keep it that way.
    var numberOfCols = tbl.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCols; i++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.id = "row" + (tbl.rows.length - 1) + "cell" + counter;  
        
        // Now, we'll create a new button, place that button in the new cell and
        // set up a click event handler for it.
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.textContent = cell.id;
        btn.id = "btn" + tbl.rows.length + counter;
        
        // Add a click event handler 
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert("You clicked cell: " + this.id);
        });
        
        // And now include the button in the cell
        cell.appendChild(btn);
        
        counter++;  // Increment the counter after using it
    }
}
```

```css
td { border:1px solid black; }

td:nth-child(2) { cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn_add_row">Add Row</button>
<table class="table table-hover" id="sample_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th id='calculate'>Column B</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <!-- sample of the td I'd like the function to generate -->
            <td id='calculate'>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and the why I shouldn't handle adding rows in that manner.  The purpose of the question though is how to bind an event to a specific cell in the new row after clicking the Add Row button.

Comment: @jeffm I have updated my answer to show a click event handler being added to the last cell of each new row. Because we are not using `onclick` and instead using the more standard `.addEventListener()`, the process works easily. You'll notice that the code doesn't attempt to pass `this` into the callback (as `this` may not always point to the same object) and that the callback is not provided as a string, but as an actual function reference.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, I learned quite a bit from your response.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

The `onclick` expects a function. So to solve your problem, change

```
 table.rows[i].onclick='callEvent(this)';
```

to

```
 table.rows[i].onclick=callEvent;
```

The second thing is, the parameter on an event is actually the event, and `this` refers to the element:

```
function callEvent(event) {
     console.log('Calculate event fired!');
     // "event" is the event
     // "this" is the element
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
missing need to second bracket end and use this callEvent(this) without single inverted comma.

Like this...

<script type="text/javascript">
// Code to add a row to the table and assign properties to new row
function addRow() { 
    var table = document.getElementById("sample_table");
    var lastRow = table.length;
    var numberOfCols = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(lastRow);
    for (var i=0;i<numberOfCols;i++) {
        row.insertCell(i);       
        if (table.rows[0].cells[i].id === 'calculate') {
// The calculate id will appear on the TD after running
            table.rows[i].id = 'calculate';
// The onclick event will not appear on the TD afer running
            table.rows[i].onclick=callEvent(this);
        }
    }
}
function callEvent(element) {
                console.log('Calculate event fired!');
}
</script>
```

Comment: `table.rows[i].onclick=callEvent(this);` is incorrect. That will invoke the `callEvent` function immediately and whatever the return value from that function is (which is nothing in this example) would become the value of the `onclick` property. If you were going to use `onclick` (and you shouldn't, you should use `.addEventListner()` instead), the line would need to be: `table.rows[i].onclick= function() { callEvent(this); }`.